# How to sum values of a given key and group by a different key? Pymongo/Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Apologies if the question is confusing, I'm not entirely sure how to word the question. What I'm trying to do should be apparent from the example hopefully.

I have an app consisting of some data regarding music tracks. Users upload a track and people vote on it. Here is a part of my tracks collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c98e400c0b156250eeda15c"
    },
    "track_title": "I Heard It Through The Grapevine",
    "description": "A nice track description",
    "date_added": "25 March 2019 14:52",
    "artist": "Marvin Gaye",
    "genre": "Soul",
    "upvotes": 10,
    "youtube_link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hajBdDM2qdg",
    "year": 1968,
    "user_name": "Christine"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c990754c0b1563bbbc577a2"
    },
    "track_title": "Snow",
    "description": "Foo bar spam eggs",
    "date_added": "25 March 2019 16:36",
    "artist": "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
    "genre": "Alternative Rock",
    "upvotes": 6,
    "youtube_link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifXalt3MJtM",
    "year": 2006,
    "date_added_raw": {
        "$date": "2019-03-25T16:36:52.988Z"
    },
    "user_name": "Frazer"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c938e11c0b15662ec3c79de"
    },
    "track_title": "Californication",
    "description": "I am foo, bar are you?",
    "date_added": "21 March 2019 13:53",
    "artist": "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
    "genre": "Alt Rock",
    "upvotes": 10,
    "youtube_link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlUKcNNmywk",
    "year": 2000,
    "user_name": "Ewan M"
}
```

What I'm trying to do is **find the artist with the most upvotes** across the collection.

Ideally, the process would be something like:

1. Get the total upvotes for each artist
2. Sort by upvotes descending

In the case of the example collection above, I would get something like:

```
{
    "artist": "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
    "total_upvotes": 16,
}

{
    "artist": "Marvin Gaye",
    "total_upvotes": 10,
}
```

I could then work with the resulting collection, getting not only the most popular artist but maybe the second and third most popular as well.

So far I'm able to sum all the upvotes across the collection (i.e. the total votes cast across all tracks)

```
# Get the total number of upvotes cast on the app
# First, get a list of all the upvote values
all_upvotes_list = list(tracks_collection.find( { },
                                { 'upvotes': 1, '_id' :0 }
                            ))

# Iterate through the list and sum the values
all_upvotes = sum(item['upvotes'] for item in all_upvotes_list)
```

But I'm not entirely sure where to take it from there, or even if I'm going in the right direction. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Start by learning the mongodb aggregation framework: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, was easy enough in the end.

Group by artist, and then sum the upvotes:

```
db.tracks.aggregate([
                     { '$group': { '_id': "$artist", 'total': { '$sum': '$upvotes' } } },
                     { '$sort': { 'total': -1 } }
                   ])
```